# Links don't redirect with React DOM Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am trying to use the `react-dom-router` package within my React app but I am not being "redirected" successfully to the component. It only works when I refresh the page or access via the URL.

This is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import NavMenu from "./components/NavMenu/NavMenu";
import Contact from "./components/Contact/Contact";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <NavMenu />

          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my **NavbarMenu** component's code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class NavMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar bg='light' expand='lg'>
          <Navbar.Brand>Company name</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className='mr-auto'>
            <Nav.Link>
              <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link>
              <Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default NavMenu;
```

I guess the code for **Home** & **Contact** components aren't relevant.

So, when I visit my React app default page `http://localhost:3000/` I see the navbar with their links. But when I click in a link, the URL changes but nothing happens until I refresh the page or access from the URL.

I was following [this tutorial](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to get this done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its s because you are using `Router` twice, first in `App.js` and then again in `NavMenu`. We only need to wrap the App container (entry point) with `Router`.

Remove the `<Router>` from `NavMenu` component. Write it like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class NavMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar bg='light' expand='lg'>
        <Navbar.Brand>Company name</Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav className='mr-auto'>
          <Nav.Link>
            <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link>
            <Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default NavMenu;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I get this error when I change like you say: `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

Comment: are you using Router any other place also? can you share the full code github link?

Comment: These were the only files I modified. I didn't use another `<Router>` somewhere else. I used `create-react-app` to generate the code...

Answer (score 0):

After Searching for long time on Stack, found your answer.

> Remove `React.StrictMode` - it prevents it from redirecting. It actually does but you have to refresh your page to see it.

Above sentence meaning, Go to your `index.js` file, you will find

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <App/>
<React.StrictMode>
```

Remove the `React.StrictMode` tag, save and reload the project. It should work!

Comment: ... what answer are you referring to? give a link to it please